# C# - Get open windows is not working as it should

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a system service that starts another application. This application (written in C#) at some point needs to get all the opened windows (applications) and list their names.

I used `EnumWindow` (from Win32), i used `Process.GetProcesses()` and `process.MainWindowTitle` (from C#) all i get is this:

> Process: UI0Detect
>
> Window title: Interactive Services Detection

If I run that application by hand it gives me all the windows as it should. But when the system service runs the app all i get is this one service.

How can i make the app get me the correct list of active windows?

Thank you

Comment: What account is the system service running under?  Is it one with administrative level permissions on the machine?

Comment: yes. I installed it from my account (also with administrative rights) and is running from Administrator

Comment: Are you using Windows Seven? If so, I'm not so sure a service can access those informations..

Comment: yes. windows 7, and sorry the service is running under Local System Account wich is my account. But the service is not the one acesing the info, the app started by the service is the one. Same app started directly by me is giving me the correct information.

Comment: @AndreiBaisan: when you manually run the app, you run it with your user, that cannot be "Local System Account", it's another one for sure! So, set the service to run under your credentials and try again. Scott's answer seems the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows services do not run in the same "session" as a normal program, so the 2nd started program also starts in the special session when your service launches it. You will need to use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and create your second app in the user session you want to monitor.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on writing interactive services for more information.

Comment: uuuuuu you are so smart! Thanks! This really helps me. It works now.